# How can I generate a list from a Javascript Array filtered based on local storage value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a page which displays an HTML list that has been filtered using a value stored in localStorage. I have only been able to display the full array, or nothingat all.

Below is sample code from my project which demonstrates this problem. The code is a collection of snippets I pieced together from other code samples.

I have tried to find an answer, but my JavaScript level is basic.

```
const itemList =
    [
    '<a href="#">Ryan</a>',
    '<a href="#">Shannon</a>',
    '<a href="#">Sita</a>',
    '<a href="#">Greta</a>',
    '<a href="#">Zack</a>',
    '<a href="#">Zach</a>',
    '<a href="#">Alfredo</a>',
    '<a href="#">Joe</a>',
    '<a href="#">Jeff</a>',
    '<a href="#">Cameron</a>',
    '<a href="#">Kevin</a>',
    '<a href="#">Kyle</a>',
    '<a href="#">Ron</a>',
    '<a href="#">Merriam</a>',
    '<a href="#">Shane</a>',
    '<a href="#">Stitch</a>',
    ];

const itemContainer = document.getElementById("item-list");
let searchInput = localStorage.getItem("nSearch");

searchInput.onkeyup = (event) => {
  filterBySearch(event.target.value);
};

const itemHTML = (item) => `<li>${item}</li>`;

const filterBySearch = (query = "") => {
  var renderHTML = ``;
  itemList.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
      renderHTML += itemHTML(item);
    }
  });
  itemContainer.innerHTML = renderHTML;
};

filterBySearch();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalStorage stores values as strings.

```js
let searchInput = localStorage.getItem("nSearch");
```

So, at this point, `searchInput` is a string. So, the following line won't work:

```js
searchInput.onkeyup = (event) => {
  filterBySearch(event.target.value);
};
```

If `nSearch` represents an element already in the document, then try

```js
let searchInput = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).find(el=>el.outerHTML ==  localStorage.getItem("nSearch"));
```

But if `nSearch` isn't an element in your page, you'll have to add it before you can put an `onkeyup` event listener on it.

Comment: I was unable to get this to work, but thank you for answering.

Comment: Oh, I got mixed up with what you were trying to do. I think I understand now. I'll edit my answer - see if that helps.